# keyfile in fist data Global Gateway Virtual Terminal

Tags: php

I have created a test account in global gateway virtual terminal. I got the sample code to implement it. But there is a field to give key file,

`$myorder["keyfile"] = "./YOURCERT.pem"; # Change this to the name and location of your certificate file`

I know there is an option to get the Cert file in virtual terminal account. But here I saw another field

"please keyin tax id". What is this? From where I get this tax id, while emptying this field I got an error message "Keyin information did not match.”  Please remember it’s a test account.

Does any one know this? I am new to this check out integration.

Answer (score 5):

Solved : I have created another test account . So in the mail they have mentioned 
111111111 as the Keyin Tax ID    for testing. You can download all the necessary files using this.

Please let me know how you have fixed it. I am also facing the same issue. How can we have a tax ID for the test accounts and it is not given anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to download the necessary files following bellow instruction taken from [Zen Cart](http://www.zen-cart.com/content.php?265-how-to-set-up-the-firstdata-global-gateway-api-linkpoint-api-yourpay-api-payment-module):

You need to OBTAIN and then UPLOAD YOUR Digital Certificate (.PEM) key:

1. Log in to your FirstData/LinkPoint/Yourpay account on their website
2. Click on "Support" in the Main Menu Bar.
3. Click on the word "Download Center" under Downloads in the Side Menu Box.
4. Click on the word "download" beside the "Store PEM File" section on the right-hand side of the page.
5. Key in necessary information to start download. **You will need to supply your actual SSN or Tax ID which you submitted during the merchant account boarding process.**